# Should I create two endpoints for two availability groups on the same SQL Instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I have a two node cluster running SQL Server 2012. I want to create two Availability groups within the same instance of SQL Server.

Should I add one endpoint for each AG, or shall I allow both AG's to use the same endpoint?

I have read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/the-database-mirroring-endpoint-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) but the only part pertaining to multiple endpoints relates to multiple SQL instances

> Note that if more than one server instance on a given computer requires a database mirroring endpoint, specify a different port
>   number for each endpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read [Prerequisites, Restrictions, and Recommendations for Always On availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-2017) it says

> Each server instance requires a database mirroring endpoint. Note that this endpoint is shared by all the availability replicas and database mirroring partners and witnesses on the server instance.

An endpoint is for instance of SQL Server and all Availability Groups configured within that instance can use this endpoint.